# Center image in bootstrap navbar with uneven ends

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, styling

I would like to center the brand logo in my page and it is currently to the side:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
export default function NavBar() {
return (
    <Navbar bg='light' fixed='top' className='navbar py-1 '>
        <Container>
            <HiOutlineMenuAlt4 />


                <Navbar.Brand className="justify-content-center">
                    <img src={publicgoodslogo}  width="120" height="65" ></img>
                </Navbar.Brand>

            <Navbar.Collapse className="justify-content-end">
                <Nav>
                    <Nav.Link><GoSearch /></Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
                <Navbar.Text>
                &nbsp;Cart:  
                </Navbar.Text>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
            <Nav>
            &nbsp;0
            </Nav>

        </Container>
    </Navbar>
)
```

According to the docs I should just be able to use justify-content-center but that doesn't work. Is it because I need to wrap the menu icon in something?

Comment: Try with these classes: `position-absolute top-0 start-50 translate-middle` all together instead the `justify-content-center`.  Btw, could you paste the HTML output of that?

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version and show rendered HTML, not template markup.